# Managing the camera - Fail to access camera

Tags: android, camera

I'm writing a program that accesses the camera. It worked for a while, but now it is the Camera API is throwing exceptions because the camera is still in use when I try to open it. I think this is because I am not handling it correctly in my onPause, onResume, and where I use it. Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onResume(){
    if (!getPackageManager()
            .hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No camera on this device", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    } else {
        cameraId = findFrontFacingCamera();
        if (cameraId < 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No front facing camera found.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            try {
                if (camera != null) {
                    camera.release();
                    camera = null;
                }
                camera = Camera.open(cameraId);
                try {
                    camera.setPreviewTexture(cameraTexture);
                }
                catch(IOException e){
                    Log.i("CameraHome", "could not set camera preview");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e){

            }
        }
    }
    super.onResume();}
```

Pause:

```
@Override
public void onPause(){
    stopLocationUpdates();
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putLong("timeLeft", timeLeft);
    editor.putBoolean("lockedOut", lockedOut);
    editor.apply();
    if (camera != null) {
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
    }
    super.onPause();
}
```

In use:

```
//Take picture
    camera.startPreview();
    camera.takePicture(null, null,
            new PhotoHandler(getApplicationContext()));
    camera.stopPreview();
    camera.release();
```

Got any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Every time I relaunch the application, it throws an exception saying that the camera is in use, even if I launch the default camera app and close it.

**EDIT:** The camera is being accessed, but my callback (onPictureTaken in PhotoHandler) is never being called, as if the picture isn't being captured properly.

Comment: everything looks fine i have checked it in the s3 and working fine can you give some sample that can generate the error that you got so i can help

Comment: Thats just it. Those are the only instances where I call methods on camera. I have a feeling that I messed up the camera by not releasing it to the system. And now even though I have proper code, it still doesn't have access because I messed up before... In which case I'm wondering if there is a way to reset the camera

Comment: `camera.startPreview();
    camera.takePicture(null, null,
            new PhotoHandler(getApplicationContext()));
    camera.stopPreview();
    camera.release();` in this you have to remove the `camera.stopPreview();
    camera.release();`

Comment: I uninstalled, restarted, and reinstalled. It is accessing the camera fine now... Well it isn't telling me it can't anymore. So that's good. However it isn't capturing the image now. I call takePicture and give an onPictureTaken callback, but that callback is never entered

Comment: Fixed it I believe. I think by calling stopPreview too soon I was interrupting the process, so I moved it to my onpause command and took away the release() after I used it

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this code works. Had to uninstall, restart, and reinstall. Then my onPictureTaken callback wasn't being called. I believe this was because I was calling stopPreview too soon. I moved that to my onPause and took away the release call after the takePicture call. Works fine now